# Как вызвать дедовский метод (вывести на экран "А") внутри внука(C), если внук и отец переопределяет тот самый метод?

Tags: java

```
class A {
void print(){ System.out.println("А");}
}
class B extends A{
@Override
void print(){ System.out.println("B");}
}
}
class C extends B {
@Override
void print(){ System.out.println("С");}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Также можно оставить себе "лазейку" в отцовском классе:

```
class Ded {
    void print(){ System.out.println("A");}
}
class Batja extends Ded{
    @Override
    void print(){ System.out.println("B");}
    void print2(){super.print();}//обращается к методу деда.
}
class Vnuk extends Batja {
    @Override
    void print(){ System.out.println("C");}
    void print3(){super.print2();}//через отца выводит метод деда.
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vnuk vn = new Vnuk();
        vn.print();//переопределенный метод.
        vn.print3();//"перепрыгнувший" метод.
    }
}
```

Comment: Единственный более менее адекватный вариант ! спасибо )))

Answer (score 3):

```
class C extends B {
@Override
void print(){ System.out.println("С"); new A().print();}
}
```